WSL 2 ssh server not working
I'm trying to set up an ssh server in Ubuntu on WSL2. I have the server running in Ubuntu on port 22, and then I've configured port forwarding from port 25252 on the Windows host to port 22 in Ubuntu. I'm able to access the Ubuntu server from Windows and from other computers on my local network. I've also set up port forwarding on my router to forward external port 22222 to internal port 25252. However, when I try to ssh in using my public IP, I get "connection refused" on every port. I've added a firewall rule in Windows for port 25252 and even tried disabling my firewall entirely, but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

Post the verbose server and client logs along with the OpenSSH configuration file. That information is a minimum, likely not the last information, required to answer your question. SSHing likely will not be possible with the configuration you describe
